# How to create multiple notification in Android Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I found from this github [post](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/pull/761) that:

> Support for multiple notifications from one app using tags, as
>   specified in the W3C spec and supported by Android.

From `statusbarnotification.js` I can see:

```
NotificationMessenger.prototype.notify = function(title, body, flag)
NotificationMessenger.prototype.clear = function()
window.Notification.callOnclickByTag = function(tag)
```

But I can't find which method can be called for creating multiple notification. Can someone suggest me? Thanks!